# Basic notification in Android: check for permission (MVVM, Dagget-Hilt, Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, android-mvvm

I'm trying to add scheduled notifications to my app, built with Kotlin, Dagger-Hilt and Jetpack Compose. Here's what I have right now:

**Notifications Module**

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NotificationsModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideNotificationBuilder(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context
    ): NotificationCompat.Builder {
        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            1,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )
        return NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "Main Channel ID")
            .setContentTitle("Scheduled notification")
            .setContentText("Here's your notification")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideNotificationManager(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context
    ): NotificationManagerCompat {
        val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            "Main Channel ID",
            "Scheduled notification",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        return notificationManager
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
```

When I try to invoke `notificationsManager` in my ViewModel, I get an error that I must first check for permissions. Android Studio offers a code, but the function requires `Context`:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor (
    private val notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder,
    private val notificationManager : NotificationManagerCompat
): ViewModel() {
    fun showSimpleNotification() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                ???,
                Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return
        }
        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())
    }
}
```

What's the best approach to this, please?

Comment: You got two solutions to choose in between,
First, you could use WorkManager and this feature will provide you with Context and also help you to schedule your Notification.

Second, you can let VIEW check your permission first while launching (For example) then pass PermissionGranted as a parameter to the function inside ViewModel.

But I really like the first solution for complexity handling and also for encapsulate all this functionality inside one location